# Is it possible to calculate confidence intervals for linear and polynomial regression models in sklearn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am doing some basic forecasting using the sklearn linear and polynomial regression models. I am able to get my model up and running pretty quickly to make predictions, but I also would like to calculate the 80% confidence intervals to get the upper and lower bounds along with the predictions.

Is there an easy way to calculate those numbers using inbuilt sklearn features?

here is what my data `df` looks like:

```
+------------+------+
|    date    | cost |
+------------+------+
| 01/01/2022 |  100 |
| 02/01/2022 |  104 |
| 03/01/2022 |  107 |
| 04/01/2022 |  108 |
| 05/01/2022 |  111 |
| 06/01/2022 |  117 |
| 07/01/2022 |  120 |
| 08/01/2022 |  122 |
| 09/01/2022 |  128 |
| 10/01/2022 |  133 |
+------------+------+
```

For both models and for the next 10 days for example, I want to calculate `yhat`, `yhat_lower`, and `yhat_upper`, but I am not sure on the best way to do this. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# confidence level
confidence = .2

# your predictions
y_pred = np.array([100,104,107,108,111,117,120,122,128,133])

y_l, y_h = y_pred * (1 - confidence), y_pred * (1 + confidence)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(range(len(y_pred)), y_pred, color="green")
ax.fill_between(range(len(y_pred)), y_l, y_h, color='b', alpha=.1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: What about sklearn instead of matplotlib?

Comment: I don't think there is any in built feature on sklearn to compute a confidence intervals. I used matplotlib only to display what it looks like