# How to use standard deviation errors from curve fit to plot error bar

Tags: python, curve-fitting

I'm wondering if I understand how standard deviation works.

The curve fit function returns the parameters of a function and the their covariances using to find the standard deviation.

Can I use the the standard deviations to plot the fitting curve with the error bars.

Here is an example. I try to keep everything as simple as possible since I'm learning.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

x = np.arange(0,10)
y = np.array([5,4.8,4.7,4.5,4.4,4.5,4.8,4.9,5,5.1])

def function(x,a,b,c):
    return a*x**2+ b*x+c

plt.scatter(x,y)

parameters, pcov = curve_fit(function, x, y)

perr = np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov))

print(perr)

plt.scatter(x, function(x, parameters[0], parameters[1], parameters[2]))
```

Comment: I'm not a statistician but I don't think there is an easy way to translate the distribution of the parameter values to 'error bars' on the curve. This does sound like an application for [Gaussian Processes](https://gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW.pdf) though.  GPs do give lower and upper bounds for the distribution of possible curves that could fit the data points.  Check out the Scikit-Learn implementation for example: [Gaussian Processes](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/gaussian_process.html).

Answer (score 2):

The answer from @Bill is one way to do this.  I think there is a simpler way to do this using lmfit (disclosure: lead author).

First, it must be noted that your problem does not necessarily need an iterative curve-fitting approach, as it is a linear problem and can be solved by regression, for example with `numpy.polyfit` (which still uses least-squares). The approach here is to explore confidence bands and uncertainties with a curve-fitting method that can handle non-linear problems too.

Using lmfit, your script might look like:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from lmfit import Model

x = np.arange(0,10)
y = np.array([5,4.8,4.7,4.5,4.4,4.5,4.8,4.9,5,5.1])

def function(x, a, b, c):
    return a*x**2+ b*x+c

# first, use numpy polyfit:
a0, b0, c0 = np.polyfit(x, y, 2)

# create lmfit Model from your function:
model = Model(function)

# create Parameters with initial values from polyfit
params = model.make_params(a=a0, b=b0, c=c0)

# run the fit, save the result, print the report of values and statistics
result = model.fit(y, params, x=x)
print(result.fit_report())

# plot data, polyfit result, and least-squares fit
plt.scatter(x, y, label='data')
plt.scatter(x, function(x, a0, b0, c0), marker='+', label='polyfit')
plt.plot(x, result.best_fit, label='least-squares fit')

# use the ModelResult to evaluate the 1-sigma and 2-sigma confidence bands
dy1 = result.eval_uncertainty(sigma=1)
dy2 = result.eval_uncertainty(sigma=2)

# plot confidence bands:
plt.fill_between(x, result.best_fit-dy1, result.best_fit+dy1,
                 color='#AAAAAA60', label='$1\sigma$')
plt.fill_between(x, result.best_fit-dy2, result.best_fit+dy2,
                 color='#AAAAAA30', label='$2\sigma$')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Note that

1. Start with `numpy.polyfit`: this will give the solution from regression.
2. Use those values as starting Parameter values for the curve fitting with lmfit.Model.
3. Use the `ModelResult.eval_uncertainty()` method to calculate uncertainty bands for the best-fit function.

The fit report is:

```
[[Model]]
    Model(function)
[[Fit Statistics]]
    # fitting method   = leastsq
    # function evals   = 5
    # data points      = 10
    # variables        = 3
    chi-square         = 0.08307576
    reduced chi-square = 0.01186797
    Akaike info crit   = -41.9058744
    Bayesian info crit = -40.9981191
    R-squared          = 0.84054557
[[Variables]]
    a:  0.02689394 +/- 0.00474101 (17.63%) (init = 0.02689394)
    b: -0.21598485 +/- 0.04432277 (20.52%) (init = -0.2159848)
    c:  4.97545455 +/- 0.08565372 (1.72%) (init = 4.975455)
[[Correlations]] (unreported correlations are < 0.100)
    C(a, b) = -0.9627
    C(b, c) = -0.8099
    C(a, c) = +0.6642
```

which shows that the polyfit values are not changed, and also shows (1-sigma) uncertainties and correlations between parameters.  The plot looks like

[image]

Comment: This is interesting. Thanks. Could you elaborate on the method used to calculate the uncertainty bounds?  Also, do you happen to know if there is an analytical solution in the case of polynomials?  (The MATLAB documentation for [polyconf](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/polyconf.html) is not very helpful).

Comment: @Bill  Lmfit calculate uncertainties in y from the covariance matrix.  See https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/model.html#calculating-uncertainties-in-the-model-function, https://www.astro.rug.nl/software/kapteyn/kmpfittutorial.html#confidence-and-prediction-interval and https://github.com/lmfit/lmfit-py/blob/468873a081bf4bcde90ab3a92e91a4119e07a913/lmfit/model.py#L1533.  I do not know of an analytic solution for polynomials - perhaps one does exist.  But, numpy.polyfit(cov=True) will return the solution and covariance matrix, so the same approach could be used.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking must be possible since there is a function in MATLAB to do this (see [polyconf](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/polyconf.html)).  I'm not sure how to do it in Python.  Someone has asked this question before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72800610/1609514) but the one answer is unsatisfactory in my opinion.  One of the comments in 2022 says "I don't think there is any in built feature on sklearn to compute a confidence intervals".

Hopefully someone has an answer for you but you may want to consider using Gaussian process regression.  It may be an alternative way to achieve what you are aiming for.

The math behind GPs is pretty intense but if you can get over this hurdle they are actually quite useful and practical tools.

Since you have chosen a curve that you believe is a good model for the true function, you can use this as a fixed mean function for the Gaussian process (see section 2.7 of Rasmussen & C. K. I. Williams, 2006).  As they say in the book:

> Simply apply the usual zero mean GP to the difference between the observations and the fixed mean function

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import ConstantKernel, RBF

x = np.arange(0, 10)
y = np.array([5, 4.8, 4.7, 4.5, 4.4, 4.5, 4.8, 4.9, 5, 5.1])

def function(x, a, b, c):
    return a * x**2+ b * x+c

# Fit polynomial (your code)
parameters, pcov = curve_fit(function, x, y)
m_func = function(x, parameters[0], parameters[1], parameters[2])

# Get the differences between measurements and the fitted curve
# We will use a GP to model these
y_gp = y - m_func

# Gaussian process parameters - adjust these to reflect 
# your beliefs about the true system
noise_std = 0.15  # measurement noise level
length_scale = 6  # the smoothness of the true function
kernel = RBF(length_scale, length_scale_bounds="fixed")
gpr = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel, alpha=noise_std**2)
gpr.fit(x.reshape(-1, 1), y_gp)

# Plot the data points
plt.scatter(x, y, label="Data")

# Plot the mean function
X_plot = np.linspace(x[0], x[-1], 101)
m_func = function(X_plot, parameters[0], parameters[1], parameters[2])
plt.plot(X_plot, m_func, linestyle='--', color='k', label='Mean function')

# Compute GP predictions
y_mean_pred, y_std_pred = gpr.predict(X_plot.reshape(-1, 1), return_std=True)

# Plot mean prediction and the confidence interval
plt.plot(X_plot, y_mean_pred + m_func, label="Mean prediction")
plt.fill_between(
    X_plot,
    y_mean_pred - 1.96 * y_std_pred + m_func,
    y_mean_pred + 1.96 * y_std_pred + m_func,
    alpha=0.5,
    label=r"95% confidence interval",
)
plt.xlabel("$x$")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: x-y plot of the GP predictions showing the 95% confidence interval]